# Get the Inserted Id Value from a SQL Table to Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, internet-explorer

I have to make an insert statement to a db Table using Javascript.
The SQL statements  are made by ActiveXObject and the open method.
The problem here is that, the open method does not return the id value that the database gave to the Primary Key of the Table.
Below you can see that I try in the same SQL statement to insert the data 
and and the same time i try to retrieve to id using the @@identity.
The "project" is only for academic purposes! I can understand the hole gap that this way has!

```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;
        var connectionstring="MyConnection";
        connection.Open(connectionstring);
        var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
        var qry = " BEGIN TRAN T1 insert into myTable (docname,date) values ("+document.getElementById('docname').value+",'"+today.toISOString().substring(0, 10)+"')  ";   
        qry = qry +  'select @@IDENTITY as id  ';   

        alert(qry);

        rs.Open(qry, connection);


        rs.MoveFirst

        var docid = rs.fields(0)
        alert(docid);
        rs.close;
        connection.close; 

//notice that  the Mytable has 3 col,the ID, docname and date
```

Comment: You really need to parametrise that query; it's wide open to injection.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your application environment? It's very strange for a JavaScript program to have access to a database connection directly. Classic ASP pages support JScript as a JavaScript-like alternative to VBScript, but the `document.getElementById` call tells me that you must be in a client/browser context rather than an ASP/server context. (We can ignore the SQL injection risk for now as it's not the focus of the question.) Also, what is the output of your program? And is the new record actually being inserted into your database? (Check using a SQL console like SSMS.)

Comment: Have you used F12 tools to see if there's any error in console? Have you defined today? I think there should be `var today = new Date();`. And have you missed the single quotes of the value of `docname` in `qry`?

Answer (score 0):

@JordanRieger The case is only a search - development  SPA that run on IE. So the Jscript that runs on the same file with the Html  connect to the DB. As you totally understand the javascript get the values from the DOM through the document.getElementById!
Now the problem to my case was, when i had to make an insert statement and get back the id of the row of the table.
The problem there was that  i tried from the same connection (i had to due to RDBMS) to make 2 sql statements one for the insert and one for the Select @@identity. The response of the RDBMS to the above situation is to sent you back two lines of messages one for the insert (i.e 1 row affect) and one another for the select stametent.
But the  " rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset")" waits only for one respone (not for data -- but for messages)
So i had to insert at the SQL query the "set nocount on " statement in order to avoid the messages.
I think that this may be usefull generally when we use datasets with native sql!
Thanks you guys anyway!